# How to iterate through Parent Child list

Tags: apex, related-list

I was wondering if someone can help me with the following

I have a parent child relationship between Tenant_Qtr_Charge__c (PARENT) and Tenant_Qtr_Charge__c(CHILD)

I would like to iterate through all parents and children data specific to the parent but my code is outputting the Parent items and adding all children various other parents to the first record.

Please see my code below.

```
List<Tenant_Qtr_Charge__c> queryResults = [SELECT 
                                           Account_Name__c,Open_Accounts_Number_Tenant__c,Method_of_Payment__c,
                                           Current_Quarter__c,  
                                           Total_Charges__c, 
                                           Total_Monthly_Charge__c, 
                                           Total_Monthly_Fixed_Charges__c,VAT_Amount__c,VAT_Code__c,
                                           (SELECT 
                                           Cost_centre__c, 
                                           Item_Description__c, 
                                           Product_Description__c
                                           FROM Tenant_Qtr_Charge_Additional_Fees__r) 
                                           FROM Tenant_Qtr_Charge__c Where Current_Quarter__c =: run.Current_Quarter__c and Invoice_Date__c >: date.parse(strGenerateInvoiceFrom) and Invoice_Date__c <=: date.parse(strGenerateInvoiceTo)];

for(Tenant_Qtr_Charge__c u: queryResults) {    
    for(Tenant_Qtr_Charge_Addtional_Fees__c s : u.Tenant_Qtr_Charge_Additional_Fees__r) {
        //================= Main Additional Charges Goes here
        AdditionalAmount =  s.Sub_Total__c;

        if(AdditionalAmount > 0) {            
            DCount1='D'+','+s.Product_Description__c+','+AdditionalAmount+','+s.VAT_Code__c+','+s.Cost_centre__c+','+s.Expense_Code__c+'\n';            
        }        
        finalDstr  = finalDstr + DCount1;        
    }

    if (u.Total_Monthly_Charge__c > 0) {        
        count=count+1;                
    }       
    //================= Main Tenant_Qtr_Charge__c Goes here
}
```

Comment: Will you explain a bit briefly where you are getting error.

Comment: Well, your query and loop structure seem fine to me, the only thing that I'm seeing is that you never reset your `AdditionalAmount`, `DCount1`, `finalDstr`, or `count` variables. It could be as simple as setting these variables to 0 (for integers) or the blank string ('') before you start your inner loop (over related child records). It might help if you were to [edit] your question to include an example of the output you expect, and the output that you're currently seeing from the code you've provided.

Comment: @DerekF Thanks very much. You suggestion sorted my problem.  I was not resetting DCount1, finalDstr.